# What subversion tool support both Visual Studio 2010 and Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, dreamweaver

I'm new at subversion and trying to setup a server to store and manage our projects. I've searched for a while but still couldn't find one that support both Visual Studio 2010 and Dreamweaver CS5. Is there such SVN tool exists?

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) makes a plugin for Visual Studio to give you subversion commands within the IDE (commit, etc). I don't know if there is a plugin for Dreamweaver to integrate subversion commands.

You could always use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) from Explorer to handle all your subversion actions.

You may be able to find a plugin for Dreamweaver but it doesn't need to be the same as the one you use within Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually CS5 supports subversion out of the box... At least the basic commands (commit, update, checkout)... not sure if it supports props, copy, etc..

Comment: I had a similar answer but he asked about setting up a server.  I'm not sure if the OP is confused or what though.

Comment: @pete yeah i wasn't sure so I thought i would add my notes. Forgot the "If you mean within your IDE" prefix

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean you are looking for a server that supports both Visual Studio 2010 and Dreamweaver?

Subversion will work fine with your Visual Studio 2010 files as well as Dreamweaver files.  I'm assuming we are talking about code files which are nothing more than text.  You don't need anything special to make a Subversion server work with a specific software suite.

Answer (score 1):

In light of Pete's comments on my other answer I thought I could provide an answer about setting up a subversion server:

VisualSVN also provide a really easy to install SVN package called [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). If you've never set up an SVN server before this is a great way to start. The Readme from my old version describes it as a package that contains everything and it includes SVN, Apache and an MMC span-in for management.